# Как получить GET параметр JS?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Всем привет. Как получить с помощью JS GET параметры?

```
http://домен.com/js/chat.js?id=1&location=http://site.ru
```

Как вытащить ИД и ссылку с помощью JS?

Comment: [purl.js](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl) в помощь: purl().param('id')

Comment: [такой вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/287469/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-get-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-javascript) уже был

Answer (score 3):

В js есть интерфейс который определяет служебные методы для работы со строкой запроса url более подробно тут https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams:

```
var url = new URL('http://wer.com/js/chat.js?id=1&location=http://site.ru');

var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.search.substring(1));

var id = searchParams.get("id"),
    loc = searchParams.get("location");

console.log("id=" + id + " location=" + loc);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var params = window
    .location
    .search
    .replace('?','')
    .split('&')
    .reduce(
        function(p,e){
            var a = e.split('=');
            p[ decodeURIComponent(a[0])] = decodeURIComponent(a[1]);
            return p;
        },
        {}
    );

console.log( params['data']);//Получите ваши параметры
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот функция, которой я пользуюсь. Будет работать не зависимо от версии браузера. Возвращает объект с параметрами

```js
function getUrlParams(url = location.search){
  var regex = /[?&]([^=#]+)=([^&#]*)/g, params = {}, match;
  while(match = regex.exec(url)) {
      params[match[1]] = match[2];
  }
  return params;
}
```